# Pronunciation of ∞ used in Japanese text

Tags: pronunciation, slang

How to pronounce `∞` in the context below?

> 実はそのリスクが顕在化したら∞だったりするんじゃないか、というようなこと。
>   ∞ったのはそれによって自分の人生が完全に変わってしまう可能性があるっていう意味。

---

Context: The author of an article discusses what he really meant in this sentence of his article:

> 一緒にいたい人と一緒にいないというリスクはそのリスクが顕在化したら全てが根本的に変わってしまうぐらい重要な要素なのではないかと言うことです。

Here is what he said just before the ∞ sentences:

> いいたい事としては、ちょっと離れても仕方ないと判断したときに、その仕方ないっていう判断の根拠にしたリスクを過小評価してないかということかな。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reasonable interpretation in this context is that ∞ stands for 無限大{むげんだい} ("infinity"), in other words, "incalculable(-y large)".

∞ったのは in the second line is, with high probability, a mistype for ∞っ**て**のは (contraction of っていうのは = というのは). With this correction you can read the sentence through as "(Why I wrote) the sign ∞ is for it means..."